# Python: Why can't I use `super` on a class?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, super

Why can't I use `super` to get a method of a class's superclass?

Example:

```
Python 3.1.3
>>> class A(object):
...     def my_method(self): pass
>>> class B(A):
...     def my_method(self): pass
>>> super(B).my_method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    super(B).my_method
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'my_method'
```

(Of course this is a trivial case where I could just do `A.my_method`, but I needed this for a case of diamond-inheritance.)

According to `super`'s documentation, it seems like what I want should be possible. This is `super`'s documentation: (Emphasis mine)

> `super()` -> same as `super(__class__,
>   <first argument>)`
>
> **`super(type)` -> unbound super object**
>
> `super(type, obj)` -> bound `super`
>   object; requires `isinstance(obj, type)`
>
> super(type, type2) -> bound super
>   object; requires issubclass(type2,
>   type)
>
> [non-relevant examples redacted]

Comment: I deleted my answer - I got the same error. Very strange, will look into it a little more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278) it seems like I just need to call `super(B, B).my_method`:

```
>>> super(B, B).my_method
<function my_method at 0x00D51738>
>>> super(B, B).my_method is A.my_method
True
```

Comment: Glad the linked source helped. :)

Comment: Remember that this will give you unbound methods; the reason you normally need to say `super(B, self)` is to get a super object bound to an object, to retrieve bound methods.

Comment: ... this looks really weird to me but works perfectly in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 8):

It looks as though you need an instance of B to pass in as the second argument.

http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275

Comment: +1, Good read, part 2/3 of this article series describes the exact problems and real use case for `unbound super objects`: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278 (The secrets of unbound super objects)